# How to do I save (Export) my Office Communicator Contacts?

Tags: contacts, communicator

When we upgrade to our new version of Office IT said our Communciator contacts will be nuked. 
Is there a way to export the contacts to a text/xml file of somesort to import once we upgrade? Or where is the contact groups and names saved to?

To clarify I don't want to export Outlook contacts, I want to exports the groups and users within Microsoft Office Communciator 2007.

Comment: Okay I think I found it http://blogs.technet.com/b/markbarr/archive/2010/04/21/how-to-export-your-communicator-2007-contacts.aspx

Comment: [Export] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841869/how-to-export-import-ms-office-communicator-contacts

Comment: [Import]
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/communicatorcontacts/thread/3aa6415d-86a7-4e35-b222-6cca1647eccc

Answer (score 0):

How to Export Communicator 2007 Contacts  (Client Side Process)

(this is not pretty but it is an “export”)

1. Enable logging in Communicator (Tools, Options, General: ‘Turn on logging in Communicator’)
2. Sign out and back in
3. Open %USERPROFILE%\TRACING on the client
4. Locate the most recent Communicator-uccapi-0.uccapilog log file
5. Open this log file (NOTEPAD or SNOOPER)
6. Search for containers xmlns (this is a list of all contacts you are subscribed to)
7. NOTE: Search for subscribers xmlns, it comes next (this is a list of all contacts subscribed to you)

to import simply copy from NOTEPAD and paste into the search bar in Communicator.  Assuming the user is not on your contact list, you may now add them.